# Db2 select query with group by clause throws error?

Tags: sql, group-by, db2

I want to get Distinct values of `SERIAL_NUM` and `EMP_NAME` but the below query throws an error.

```
SELECT SERIAL_NUM,EMP_NAME,NOTESID FROM DB2INST1.EMP_HC 
GROUP BY 
SERIAL_NUM,EMP_NAME,NOTESID 
HAVING   
FUNC_VP ='Bob '  AND 
VICE_PRES ='Bob'  AND 
DIRECTOR ='Michael'  AND 
THIRD_LINE ='Linda '
```

error

`DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-119, SQLSTATE=42803, SQLERRMC=FUNC_VP, DRIVER=3.63.123`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want "*distinct values of SERIAL_NUM and EMP_NAME*" you need to tell the database which `notesid` to pick if there are multiple combinations of `serial_num` and `emp_name`. If you don't care which `notesid` you get, you can e.g. use `min()`

```
SELECT serial_num,
       emp_name,
       min(notesid) as notesid
FROM db2inst1.emp_hc 
WHERE func_vp ='Bob '  
  AND vice_pres ='Bob'  
  AND director ='Michael'  
  AND third_line ='Linda'  
GROUP BY serial_num,emp_name
```

Comment: however when i use min(notesid) i cannot get the value since  resultSet.getString("NOTESID");  throws an error when i try to iterate through the result set ?

Comment: @user3398326: did you use the column alias the way I did? (`as notesid`)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use HAVING on fields that does not appear in the GROUP BY clause, since the field may then have more than one value within a group.

What you probably want to do is use plain WHERE to filter out the interesting rows, and then GROUP BY;

```
SELECT SERIAL_NUM,EMP_NAME,NOTESID 
FROM DB2INST1.EMP_HC 
WHERE FUNC_VP ='Bob '  
  AND VICE_PRES ='Bob'  
  AND DIRECTOR ='Michael'  
  AND THIRD_LINE ='Linda '  
GROUP BY SERIAL_NUM,EMP_NAME,NOTESID
```

...or if you for some reason *need* to use HAVING, you'll need to add the fields FUNC_VP, VICE_PRES, DIRECTOR and THIRD_LINE to the GROUP BY;

```
GROUP BY SERIAL_NUM,EMP_NAME,NOTESID,FUNC_VP,VICE_PRES,DIRECTOR,THIRD_LINE
```